# Anchor view jumps when PopupMenu opens up (but not down)

Tags: android, popupmenu

I've set up a long click listener on a view in my Activity layout (it's a view showing a colour swatch).  A long click will bring up a PopupMenu with a number of choices.

It works OK except I'm finding that when the anchor view is positioned towards the bottom of the screen when I long click on it, so that the popup menu will open upwards from it, the anchor view doesn't remain where it is but jumps up to the middle of the screen.  The menu opens up and functions correctly, it's just that jump I want to avoid.

Strangely, it doesn't happen when the anchor view is towards the top of the screen with the popup menu opening downwards... the anchor view remains where it is.

Here is an example before long clicking... the anchor view for the popup menu is the green colour swatch near the bottom of the screen:

[image]

And here is what I see immediately after the menu pops up... the green colour swatch has jumped up to the middle of the screen:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

popup_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourCopy"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourCopy"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourCopySingle"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourCopySingle"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourCopyMultiple"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourCopyMultiple"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourEndMultiple"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourEndMultiple"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourPaste"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourPaste"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/colourReset"
        android:title="@string/menu_colourReset"/>

</menu>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;


View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MyActivity.this, v);
        popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch( item.getItemId() ) {
                    case R.id.colourCopy:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourCopy clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.colourCopySingle:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourCopySingle clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.colourCopyMultiple:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourCopyMultiple clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.colourPaste:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourPaste clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.colourEndMultiple:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourEndMultiple clicked");
                        break;
                    case R.id.colourReset:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Menu colourReset clicked");
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();

        return true;
    }
};


View colorView = view.findViewById(setting.viewId);
colorView.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer, but a workaround...

As per my original post, I had been getting the `PopupMenu` from the v7 support library:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
```

But if I get it from the standard library, it all seems to work without the reported glitch:

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
```